# How to reference a variable defined in setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I've got the following `setup.py`:

```
import itertools


dependencies = {
  'minimal': ['numpy', 'requests'],
  'option-a': ['scipy'],
  'option-b': ['matplotlib']
}

setup(
  install_requires=dependencies['minimal'],                           # minimal dependencies
  extras_require={
      'all': list(itertools.chain(*dependencies.values())),           # all dependencies included
      **{k: v for k, v in dependencies.items() if k != 'minimal'},    # each extra dependency group
  },
  # other setup parameters omitted
)
```

I used a variable `dependencies` to avoid duplicating lists of dependencies and to make it easy to maintain. It seems like a good approach.

I'd like to write a function `verify_optional_extras('option-a')` which will check if the packages for the `option-a` extras were installed.

If I could access the `dependencies` variable defined in `setup.py` I could easily write a verification function for those packages.

Possible answers to this question:

1. Show me how to access `dependencies` in `setup.py`.
2. Tell me a better way to organize optional dependencies.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the variable in your main script?  Not during build process?

Comment: Correct, my goal is to write a function in main code to assert if the appropriate optional packages have been installed. Those optional packages are defined here and I was hoping to not need to keep two sets of identical lists in different places (else someone will almost certainly forget to update one of them someday in the future)

Comment: what does your folder structure look like? The script from which you want to access setup.py and your setup.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access the information from within the installed package,
then you should not attempt to access the `setup.py` source directly because **it will not actually be there**. Once your code is installed into site-packages, the installer i.e. the `setup.py` file itself is gone. You may be able to access it from within a development source tree, like a git checkout, but the same won't be true when your package gets installed and used by someone else.

For a wheel installation, there was never even a `setup.py` inside the `.whl` file in the first place. It's just a zip file, unzip it and see for yourself! But the missing `setup.py` is true even in the case of a source distribution installation (`mypkg-1.0.tar.gz`), or anything installed from pip (which first builds a wheel file and then installs the wheel).

Instead you will need something like this, to access the dependency data from the package metadata:

```
# from within your my_module:
from importlib.metadata import requires
reqs = requires(__package__)
```

The structure is a little different, so you may need to parse it back to a dict, but all the information is there:

```
>>> requires("mypkg")
['numpy',
 'requests',
 'numpy; extra == "all"',
 'requests; extra == "all"',
 'scipy; extra == "all"',
 'matplotlib; extra == "all"',
 'scipy; extra == "option-a"',
 'matplotlib; extra == "option-b"']
```

These are requirement lines, if you need a tool for parsing them when you go to verify the optional deps installation, then you can use the [packaging](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/requirements.html) module for that:

```
>>> from packaging.requirements import Requirement
>>> req = Requirement('scipy >= 1.6; extra == "option-a"')
>>> req.name
'scipy'
>>> req.specifier
<SpecifierSet('>=1.6')>
>>> "1.7.3" in req.specifier
True
>>> "1.5" in req.specifier
False
>>> req.marker
<Marker('extra == "option-a"')>
```